# Replacing (not modifying) 'const' values, legal?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, declaration, string-literals

Observe the following code:

```c
const char *str1 = "foo";
printf("1.1: %s\n", str1);
str1 = "bar";
printf("1.2: %s\n\n", str1);

const char *str2[] = { "foo", "bar" };
printf("2.1: %s\n", str2[0]);
str2[0] = "baz";
printf("2.2: %s\n\n", str2[0]);

char *str3 = malloc(4);
strcpy(str3, "foo"); 
const char *str4[] = { str3, "bar" };
printf("3.1: %s -- %s\n", str4[0], str4[1]);
//str4[0][0] = 'z';
str4[0] = "bar";
str4[1] = "baz";
printf("3.2: %s -- %s\n", str4[0], str4[1]);
free(str3);
```

Wrapping it in a standard `main` function and compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o test test.c`, this gives no warnings and the output is:

```
1.1: foo
1.2: bar

2.1: foo
2.2: baz

3.1: foo -- bar
3.2: bar -- baz
```

When uncommenting the only commented line, gcc complains `error: assignment of read-only location ‘*str4[0]’`. Of course this is expected, I only added that bit for completeness.

By my understanding all the other assignments are valid because I'm not modifying the already existing read-only memory, I'm replacing it in its entirety with **another** memory block (which is then also marked read-only). But is this legal throughout all C compilers, or is it still implementation-dependent and therefore can it result in undefined behaviour? It's a little hard to find good information on this because it always seems to be about modifying the **existing** memory through pointer magic or casting the `const` away.

Comment: You are not "replacing" memory, you are making a pointer refer to a different memory location. That operation is valid since the pointers themselves are not `const`

Comment: You're not modifying or "replacing" (whatever that means) any read-only memory -- you're modifying the pointers, which are not const, so are not in read-only memory.  You are probably confusing the memory of the pointers and the memory the pointers are pointing at in your head -- those are two different locations.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure how to call it, with "replace" I indeed mean "make it point to different (read-only) memory". I didn't mean to imply that the same memory section is replaced with different contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration

```
const char *str1 = "foo";
```

the pointer (variable) `str1` is not constant. It is the string literal pointed to by the pointer `str1` that is constant. That is the (non-constant) pointer `str1` points to a constant object of the type `const char`.

So you may not change the literal pointed to by the pointer like for example

```
str1[0] = 'g';
```

But you may change the variable `str1` itself because it is  not constant

```
str1 = "bar";
```

To declare the pointer `str1` as a constant pointer you should write

```
const char * const str1 = "foo";
```

In this case you may not write

```
str1 = "bar";
```

Because now the pointer `str1` itself is constant.

Pay attention to though in C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays nevertheless you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

That is you may not write

```
char *str1 = "foo";
str1[0] = 'g';
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for. I'm aware you shouldn't change a literal and it will likely just throw a bus error once the compiled program reaches that part. I wasn't aware about making the pointers **themselves** constant though. So it looks like my example is indeed valid standard C and thus it should work exactly the same across all compilers. If you could add a little mention about that then I can accept your answer. :>

Comment: @Sahbi There is written clear in the answer that "But you may change the variable `str1` itself because it is  not constant"

Comment: Yeah I know, but the question was "is this legal throughout all C compilers, or is it still implementation-dependent and therefore can it result in undefined behaviour" and it doesn't quite answer that explicitly. Might seem a little pedantic but imo it makes for a better answer.